# What 1960s or earlier short story features a cloudy Planet named Naxos and a lens?

Tags: story-identification

From my brother, once again: on an unusually cloudy planet, the inhabitants offer sacrifice under what may be a Fresnel lens.  He is reasonably certain that the planet is named Naxos.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like "Polaris and the Immortals" from Fantastic Novels, SEP 1950. 
Polaris will destroy Olrec's planet with King Bel-ar armada. The "priests" Sacrifice victims to their god Shamar / Shammar with a giant lens.
(spoiler alert) Said lens used to kill King Bel-ar 
Rutharians and goddess Glorian may jog a memory.

Comment: Sounds likely; waiting for brother to verify.

Comment: Brother says no....sacrifices were not beings, but harvest products.

Answer (score 1):

This might be "[Regulations](http://hell.pl/szymon/Baen/The%20Baltic%20War/Planets%20of%20Adventure/0743471628__20.htm)" by Murray Leinster.  It was published in 1948, I found it in the collection "[Planets of Adventure](http://hell.pl/szymon/Baen/The%20Baltic%20War/Planets%20of%20Adventure/0743471628_toc.htm)".

There is a planet with unusual weather - something about the way water doesn't collect in the atmosphere, no clouds or rain, but instead clings to the jungle, runs as dew.  Not always overcast, but unusual.  The planet is Oryx, not Naxos, and the inhabitants are called Honkies.  They sacrifice stones, shiny crystals, to the Dew-god.  There is the use of lenses - water droplets act as lenses and burn vegetation from underneath them, thee crystals being offered are valued because of the lens-similarity, there is a giant focal-point where the dew and crystals both gather, and where

> one of the humans visiting the planet manages to sacrifice himself, jumping in the pool because he thought the crystals were diamonds.

There are a number of details that are different from the question, but also enough general similarities, and oddly-specific opposites, that I thought it worth mentioning - in case the story was being slightly mis-remembered.  In any case, I hope you find it.